# Could not mount the media/drive '/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED)

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to install latest VBoxGuestAddtions.iso ([link](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/)) in Ubuntu system. When I mount ISO image as CD-ROM I see this error:

**Could not mount the media/drive '/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED).**

Answer (score 0):

To make it work I had to add my user to vboxusers group.

```
$ sudo usermod -aG vboxusers $USER
```